# Textbox in ribbon (same with all keyboard input controls)

Tags: wpf, textbox, ribbon

I need to insert a TextBox into the ribbon, but it doesn't work.
All numeric and alphabetical inputs have no effect. The only characters allowed are space, delete, backspace and Arrow buttons.

I tried with TextBox control and RibbonTextBox too. Maybe they are kicked out for shortcuts...

Any idea ?

Comment: please, post code. And what library of Ribbon do you use? `FluentRibbon` or built-in library `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`?

Comment: I use the Microsoft RibbonControlsLibrary.dll (4.0.0.11019) using full MVVM. Hard to put a simple code working in there. There are many files to implement it the full MVVM way :o(. When you say "built-in Library", you mean it's included in the Framework now... Ishould try to quickly convert the project to see if it works better.